# Php getting total amount of duplicate values from a SQL query

Tags: php, sql

I have this query which returns a list of rows as well as the amount of time they are repeated, with a column TotalCount :

```
SELECT X,
COUNT(*) as TotalCount
FROM table
GROUP BY X HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

I execute this query in PHPMyadmin :

```
[X] [TotalCount]
 A       5
 B       6
```

I try to include the query in my script, but the following gives me '2' :

```
echo $result->num_rows;
```

How to get the '11' in PHP?

EDIT:

My query is :

```
$sql="
    SELECT X,
    COUNT(*) as TotalCount
    FROM table
    GROUP BY X HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
    ";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
echo $result->num_rows;
```

I am trying to do something like

```
echo $row[TotalCount];
```

The initial table is

```
[X]
A
A
A
A
A
B
B
B
B
B
B
```

Comment: What does your table look like?

Comment: if I understand you correctly when you run the query in phpmyadmin it works fine when you insert the query in php code it only returns 2?

Comment: Hi, you must put the PHP code your are using actually... What is `$result` and what represents `num_rows` in it.

Comment: guradio in phpmyadmin it works fine because this query has created a column TotalCount with the amount of repetitions. But I do not know how to get this 'displayed' via PHP

Comment: I believe the $result will contain the count you're looking for, numrows is a function of it which will return 2 rows, so php is not the issue. do a var_dump($result); you'll see the array

Comment: See [pdo::query](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php)

Comment: user what is the code to fetch the resulting values?

Comment: Can I ask what is the name of the array created through the query I will have to fetch results from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is behaving correctly, it returns `2` because you have 2 rows. You actually want the values of those rows so you need to [fetch](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) the result object.

```
$sql="
    SELECT X,
    COUNT(*) as TotalCount
    FROM table
    GROUP BY X HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
    ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
     echo $row['TotalCount'] . PHP_EOL; // or '<br />' if in a browser;
}
```

Comment: Glad to help. You can use `TotalCount` in your `having` and `order by` as well in place of the `count(*)`s.